# (Bukkit API) Testing if a damage is an insanceof Falling

Tags: java, events, enums, bukkit

So here is my code
    @EventHandler
    public void NoFall(EntityDamageEvent e)
    {

```
    if(e instanceof Player)
    {
        Player p = ((Player) e).getPlayer();

        if(p.hasPermission("prisonprofessional.adminmenu.nofall"))
        {
            if(e.getCause() instanceof Falling)
            {
                e.setDamage(0.0F);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

this does return an enum but how do I get it so it is an instanceof falling.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for enum values with the `==` comparator

```
if (e.getCause() == DamageCause.FALL) {
```